# Querying for Users with identical ManyToMany fields

Tags: django

This is more of a design question. My problem is that I wish to query for users that have identical selections in their manytomany fields. Is there a build-in method or combination of methods I can use to achieve this? Otherwise, I have a solution but it wouldn't be ideal. Thank you!

My Solution-

Upon the form submission, I was thinking on also storing a corresponding key which will be an integer created based on their selections. Then I can query to see if these keys are equal.

Comment: `User.objects.filter(many_to_many_field__in=[<list of relations>])`

Comment: This is querying for each individual item not checking for equality of the entire many to many model. Ex. A user is returned 6 times as they share 6 of the same classes. Thanks for your response!